# Git: Using cherry-pick to copy tags from one branch to another

Tags: git, tags, cherry-pick

I have a MASTER branch with several commits and tags. I would like to copy only the tags from MASTER into a RELEASE branch (and no other commits).

I first created an empty MASTER branch, and committed it with message only. Then I created an empty RELEASE branch.  I added several commits to MASTER with the following contents:

- C1: file1
- C2: file1, file2
- C3: file1, file2, file3

In MASTER, I created a tag T1 with C2 (which contains file1 and file2)  Now, I would like to copy tag T1 to RELEASE branch. It seemed like I need to use cherry-pick to do this.

I first note the SHA-ID of tag T1 in MASTER. Then I do:

- git checkout RELEASE
- git cherry-pick [SHA-ID of T1]

Success, but RELEASE branch now only shows file2. Shouldn't it be showing the contents of tag T1, i.e, both file1 and file2?

Again, my goal is only to have tags from MASTER (and no other commits) showing in RELEASE. Is this possible?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi rustcat, welcome on SO. You first have a master branch, then you.... create another master branch?! There's something amiss here. git doesn't allow you to do so. Also, what is this step supposed to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with this:

> ... my goal is only to have tags from MASTER (and no other commits) showing in RELEASE

This goal makes no sense in Git.  In Git, *all* reference names exist *outside* the set of commits.  Moreover, there's no container/contained relationship between names (with one constraint inherited from the way Git implements these names currently).  That is, the names `A` and `B` are entirely independent of each other.  The names `feature/X` and `feature/Y` are also entirely independent of each other.  Making any change—including creating a new name or removing an old one—has no effect on any other name.

(The exception here is that once you have the name `feature/X` or `feature/Y`, you can no longer use the name `feature` at all.  That name is now "occupied" by the `feature/` part of the other two names.  You can continue to use `feature/` to hold more names, and you can use `featur` without the final `e`, but you cannot create the name `feature` to identify an object, because `feature/` exists because of `feature/X` and/or `feature/Y`.)

Tag names are not contained in branches.  Branch names are not contained in tags.  They're all separate entities, existing along side each other.  It's up to you to organize them.  One sensible way is to use these slashes: `feature/name` is a good short name for a branch on which you and/or others are developing a new feature whose name (or code name) is *`name`*.  Branch names of the form `relbranch/name` may be good short names for organizing commits that will go into a particular release, whose name (or code name) is *`name`*.  When one particular commit, aimed at some release, has been verified by QA and is now being shipped, a tag name of the form `releases/name` may be a good short name for that release.

(Note that `git for-each-ref`, the internal Git command for dealing with references in general, is particularly happy with slash-separated name components: `git for-each-ref refs/tags/releases` iterates over all the tags in `refs/tags/releases/*`, for instance.)

#### More about tag and branch names

Tags are just pointers to commits.  That is, each commit object has its own "true name", which is a big ugly hash ID like `5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7`.  This name is unique to this one commit (which is a commit in the Git repository for Git, so unless you have a Git repository for Git, you won't have this one commit).  These true-names, by which Git accesses the object, are unweildy and useless to humans, so Git offers us names.  You can make a tag name like `v2.20.0`, and its main function—or sometimes, one of two such functions—is that it replaces the need to memorize `5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7`.

This is also true for branch names, but with a couple of important differences:

- A branch name is expected to *change* over time.  That is, after you made commit C1 (whatever its actual hash ID was), the name `master` is a name for commit C1.  But then the act of making commit C2, while being on `master`, *changed* the name `master` to name commit C2 now.  When you made C3, Git changed `master` again, so that it identifies commit C3 now.
- A *tag* name is expected to be constant.  That is, if you create a tag *T* that names commit C2, *every Git everywhere*—well, every Git repository that you ever connect to your Git repository, directly or indirectly—can assume, from now on, that *T* means "commit C2".  If you, in your repository, rip out tag *T* and create a new *T* that names commit C3, all *other* Git repositories are correct if they continue to translate the name *T* to C2.  (They're also correct if they change to C3, but they're not required to change over.)
- Tag names are allowed to point *indirectly* to commits, through a tag object.  Git calls this kind of tag an *annotated tag*.  The tag object can store a bit of extra information, such as a PGP signing key saying *I, the signer, have checked that this particular commit is valid and should be used.*  That's the case for `v2.20.0` in the Git repository for Git, for instance:

  ```
  $ git cat-file -p v2.20.0
  object 5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7
  type commit
  tag v2.20.0
  tagger Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1544329907 +0900

  Git 2.20
  -----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----

  iQIzBAABCAAdFiEE4fA2sf7nIh/HeOzvsLXohpav5ssFAlwMmrMACgkQsLXohpav
  5sv6pg//VIRzIkTz+DQ4ITzWXpH41lGjhsbSN554a/Kj5W1RvHiQmzpv5HDM65vr
  Dr9DqYiP3HBOPElUTxT5iS2qgsajrRZ1yvKMEnb+YxLbix0NhkvdhJxHmsTUYmEH
  SOve1ddx9spKHEdRjgw6eyoTiG5yQgcea7XkdATeTYeJzZIfMcrXVR920ZjUi9dK
  DRambd/KGYFIPftN0EdVCVPUDrNlKvmK3RhS7arZUxFBxSGDVzGiStK0r2aSw0lb
  gT27Ygy+cz0StWL2q4kV4ghPhjpAv9QqypNNADRg9ZxDhY446V2flU67oV0PLCm/
  E4GmgkjGOphQOujWJv6Uz+6F4E1DvGx9Wt78Xbl3kXZruyhwIv/7yk53nUPxtaI5
  PjBqy+2vJPmZoUONH3/zSYlGW4ZwURatXTDe3FOK15Eq3EV+IpbRGhpuu4Ju9U3c
  L1dpTFdauiKJFuSNkrsdrJPhpX2nbgYl3PloxHWAhPzoqFGib4reRqrm12lczpRp
  BytNhs8RWwR+4CZXAFYtITFEdBLhHvWodklYnGfTFlMKs/OZ4S+XNS2LOb6Wjc3S
  EFF4U87QGnHm6vCREpKwVOMroAEOUXsrbHc3tzxrX16GlXHNWYI/fgAkD6twffE8
  GEIclUQ7v/fRFlmznDJKGOoWVDTUzwLCVeb36lmpd6w+CpRm7cc=
  =1E0P
  -----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
  ```

  (The counterpart to an annotated tag is a *lightweight tag*, which just points directly to a commit.  By default, `git describe` ignores the lightweight tags, using only the annotated ones to come up with a more human-friendly name for some raw commit hash.)

Because branch names move, they *should* be used for any case where you want people to pick up and use the new value of the old name.  Because tag names *don't* move, they *should* be used for any case where you want people to use one particular commit forever.  Because annotated tags can provide access to digital signatures, they are good for these cases as well.

#### About cherry-pick

Note that `git cherry-pick` *does* copy commits.  To do so, it first *converts* the commit to a change-set.  (This explanation is a bit handwave-y and ignores the fact that cherry-pick is implemented via the merge machinery, but is good enough for thinking about the issues.)  Remember that a commit saves a *snapshot* of every file, in the form it had when you (or whoever) made that commit.

Copying a commit as-is would not be good.  Suppose, for instance, that you want to make the same *change* (a fix) to an old release that is also going into a new release.  Taking the new-release's fixed commit (snapshot) and copying that directly into the old release-branch would make the next version of the old release 100% identical to the new release's fixed commit, instead of just importing the one fix.  So cherry-pick doesn't copy the *snapshot* at all.

To convert a commit (snapshot) to a changeset, Git must compare the commit to its immediate predecessor.  The predecessor of C3 is C2, for instance, so by comparing the snapshot in C2 to the snapshot in C3, Git can tell you what *changed* from C2 to C3.

To do a cherry-pick, then, you start by checking out some existing commit (other than C2 or C3 of course).  Typically this would be via `git checkout name`, using the name of the branch on which this particular version is being developed.  Then you tell Git: *First, figure out what **changed** in C3, with respect to C2.  Then make the **same** changes to my current not-C2 not-C3 commit, and use the result to make a new commit.*

Having made a new commit—which gets a new big ugly hash ID, different from the big ugly hash IDs of every other commit—Git writes the new commit's hash ID into the current branch name as usual.  Now, whatever *branch name* you're on now—probably not `master`, but that's up to you—refers to this new snapshot.  You can make a *new* tag to point to this new commit, but because people (and software) expect tags not to change, it's generally unwise to remove *any* existing tag and replace it with a new tag of the same name, pointing to a different commit.